# Return value after event or timeout

Tags: java, multithreading, architecture, return

I want to send a string containing login credentials to a remote host. The server should send back `"LOGIN ACCEPTED"` or `"LOGIN DENIED"` after a short time. If this occurs, I want to return `true` or `false`. If no answer is received within a given timeout, I want to return `false`.

Unfortunately, I've got no idea how to do this.

This is an experimental project, so it doesn't matter that transfer of the login credentials isn't secure.

Relevant Code:

```java
public class Client implements Closeable, DataSender {
    protected RequestHandler requestHandler;
    protected Thread clientThread;
    protected PrintWriter printWriter;

    public final int LOGIN_TIMEOUT = 5000;

    public Client(InetAddress address, RequestHandler requestHandler) {
        this.requestHandler = requestHandler;
        // ...
            this.startListening();
        // ...

    }

    protected void startListening() {
        this.clientThread = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(this.socket.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
                this.printWriter = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(this.socket.getOutputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()));
                String line;
                while (this.running) {
                    line = scanner.nextLine();

                    switch (line) {
                        case "LOGIN ACCEPTED":
                            // TODO
                            break;

                        case "LOGIN DENIED":
                            // TODO
                            break;
                        // ...
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Cannot connect to server.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        this.clientThread.setDaemon(true);
        this.clientThread.run();
    }

    public boolean login(String user, String password) {
        String data = "LOGIN\nuser=" + user + "\n+password=" + password;
        this.send(data);

        // TODO

        return false;
    }

    protected void send(String data) {
        this.printWriter.write(data);
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: So... if it's not working right, what IS it doing?

Comment: I don't know how to return true or false if the server response arrives or false if the timeout occurs before (in login(...) )

Comment: before you start waiting you need to start a timer, or schedule task and if you get a response you cancel it.  If you don't cancel the start you can close the connection and this will wake up the waiting threads.

Answer (score 0):

Set a timeout:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout(int)

The read will block for only a certain amount of time, then raise an sockettimeoutexception.  In the catch block for sockettimeout, return false.

This is *not* the same as the socket open timeout.